# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, ipynb

I'm trying to use OneHotEncoding on the categorical variables of the following dataset.

Error
[image]

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [5])
X = ohe.fit_transform(data).toarray()
```

Can someone help me to understand why this error occurs and how to solve this?

I'm trying to use the `OneHotEncoder` and here's what I've done so far:

Comment: `OneHotEncoder` is an `int`. It might have got overwritten somewhere.